AWS flutter Unhandled Exception: type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'Map<dynamic, dynamic>' in type cast
i am new to AWS on flutter , when ever i try to add online sync to data store i keep getting this error, i am using Graphql. here is my configureamplify.
also attached is a scrrenshot of the log file.
i am using flutter 3.22.2 and amplify flutter 2.1.0


tried using the AWS documentation but it leads to the same error .
uninstalled and reinstalled the Graphql api but still no help , even attempted flutter clean and upgrade

After investigation, i found out I get the error when i add datastore to Amplify.addPlugin()

AWS just release datastore 2.2.1 which solves the query on startup . but everytime yu restart the app it still has the query issue. sure it will be fixed in later versions.
